# How may I create an array of JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json

Each object represents a different user and each user has 3 properties: loginid, password, realname.

Below is what I have written. Is this cord correct?

```js
var user= [
    {"loginid":"email1@email.com", "password":1234, "realname":"A" };,
    {"loginid":"email2@email.com", "password":1234, "realname":"B" };,
    {"loginid":"email3@email.com", "password":1234, "realname":"C" };,
]
```

Comment: Drop the `;` in the end of each object ... and the `,` after the last

Comment: @MaorP JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation." That is, a way to represent javascript objects as a plain string. "JSON Object" is a misnomer. What you are creating is an Object in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, except the semicolons.

EDIT:
Actually, I think the correct way would be

```
{ "users": [
      {"loginid":"email1@email.com", "password":1234, "realname":"A" },
      {"loginid":"email2@email.com", "password":1234, "realname":"B" },
      {"loginid":"email3@email.com", "password":1234, "realname":"C" },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like LGSon said, you need to drop the ; from each line. Also you can define field namaes without " ", like this:

```
  var user= [
      {loginid:"email1@email.com", password:1234, realname:"A" },
      {loginid:"email2@email.com", password:1234, realname:"B" },
      {loginid:"email3@email.com", password:1234, realname:"C" },
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
 var user= [
      {loginid:"email1@email.com", password:1234, realname:"A"},
      {loginid:"email2@email.com", password:1234, realname:"B"},
      {loginid:"email3@email.com", password:1234, realname:"C"},
       ];
```

Answer (score 0):

that's how you can create array object JSON

```
    {
    "user": [{
            "loginid": "email1@email.com",
            "password": 1234,
            "realname": "A"
        },
        {
            "loginid": "email2@email.com",
            "password": 1234,
            "realname": "B"
        },
        {
            "loginid": "email3@email.com",
            "password": 1234,
            "realname": "C"
        }
    ]
}
```